# How can we create an object of Connection even when it's an interface?

Tags: jdbc, interface

Here we have created an object of an interface.
How's that even possible?

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","xweb","abc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are creating a instance of a class that implements the interface.  What that means is that you do not need to know the concrete class implementation of the object, just that it implements Connection, and as such has all the methods defined in interface Connection.  If you look at con.getClass(), you will see what the actual class is.

Comment: This is the class skeleton-
class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection extends oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnec
tion implements oracle.sql.BfileDBAccess,oracle.sql.BlobDBAccess,oracle.sql.Clob
DBAccess{

But i don't see any connection interface

Comment: one of those classes has to implement it, or one of the interfaces has to extend it, or some class that they extend/implement, etc.